# MS SQL Деление ID на группы по 20 штук

Tags: sql, sql-server

Понимаю вопрос нубский, но все же:
В таблице есть колонка ID, необходимо присвоить каждой 20-ке новый ID

```
ID(1-20)= ID_NEW =1
ID(21-40)= ID_NEW = 2
...
ID(n-m)=ID_NEW_2 = k
```

Попытался так:

```
ROUND ((ID&20),0)+1 AS ID_NEW
```

И так:

```
ROUND ((ID/20),0)+1 AS ID_NEW
```

Выдает совершенно странные значения.

В чем проблема?

```
ID  ID_NEW  ID_NEW_2
1   5   598
2   17  598
3   17  598
4   17  598
5   17  598
6   21  598
7   21  598
8   21  598
9   21  598
10  17  599
11  17  599
12  17  599
13  17  599
14  21  599
15  21  599
16  21  599
17  21  599
18  1   599
19  1   599
20  1   599


select 
                RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime ASC) AS ID,
                Coun_W = a.Count_W,
                DateTime=a.DateTime,
                Consumption = (a.Diff_Count_W/a.Diff_Count_AP)*1000000,
                OrderNo = b.OrderNo,
                ProductNo = b.ProductNo,
                Value = b.Value,
                Brand = b.Brand,
                BrandName = b.BrandName,
                LinkUp = b.LinkUp,
                KDF= b.KDF,
                StartDate = b.StartDate,
                CompletionDate = b.CompletionDate,


                 ROUND ((ID/20),0)+1 AS ID_NEW,

                a.Diff_Count_W,
                a.Diff_Count_AP

  FROM ( SELECT * FROM [AcetateWeight].[dbo].[WeightCounter] where Equipment IN (@Equipment) AND Diff_Count_AP>0 and Diff_Count_AP is not null
AND DateTime 
between DateAdd(Minute,1170,(@DateTime))  AND DateAdd(minute,450,DATEADD(DAY,1,(@DateTime)))) as a

  inner join 

  (SELECT * FROM [AcetateWeight].[dbo].[AW_FilterPOActuals] WHERE /*DAY=@DateTime AND Shift=@Shift and */KDF=@Equipment) as b
  ON 
a.DateTime >= b.StartDate AND a.DateTime<= b.CompletionDate
```

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "совершенно странные значения", покажите!

Comment: Обновил информацию в самом вопросе

Comment: Можете добавить не только результат работы запроса но и сам запрос тоже?

Comment: добавил  сам запрос, не знаю правда чем он поможет

Comment: А вы уверены, что у вас правильный ID берется? Вы же хотите `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime ASC)` а не ID из какой-то другой таблицы? Тогда надо переписать, потому что обращение идет не к нему

Comment: Ну да, если делать просто селект, то ID соответвует номеру строки, и вполне адекватно присваевается по времени. Я как раз Эту строку и добавил, чтобы обезопасить себя от того, что ID из другой таблици подтягиевается.   Или Вы думаете что когда деление идет, то в этот момент другой ID подтягивается?

Comment: Очевидно же, что да. Нельзя обратиться к другому полю в том же селекте вот так. Попробуйте сами, переименуйте в `ID123`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже успели заметить в комментариях - Вы делаете не то, что хотите получить.
В Вашем запросе в `ROUND ((ID/20),0)+1 AS ID_NEW,` используется не `ID` из `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime ASC) AS ID` а `ID` из какого-то подзапроса - или `a` или `b`

Вам нужно сделать еще один запрос вокруг вашего запроса, чтобы получить желаемое, как-то так:

```
select ROUND ((ID/20),0)+1 as ID_NEW 
from (
    select 
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DateTime ASC) AS ID,
        Coun_W = a.Count_W,
        DateTime=a.DateTime,
        Consumption = (a.Diff_Count_W/a.Diff_Count_AP)*1000000,
        OrderNo = b.OrderNo,
        ProductNo = b.ProductNo,
        Value = b.Value,
        Brand = b.Brand,
        BrandName = b.BrandName,
        LinkUp = b.LinkUp,
        KDF= b.KDF,
        StartDate = b.StartDate,
        CompletionDate = b.CompletionDate, 
        a.Diff_Count_W,
        a.Diff_Count_AP
      FROM ( SELECT * FROM [AcetateWeight].[dbo].[WeightCounter] where Equipment IN (@Equipment) AND Diff_Count_AP>0 and Diff_Count_AP is not null
    AND DateTime 
    between DateAdd(Minute,1170,(@DateTime))  AND DateAdd(minute,450,DATEADD(DAY,1,(@DateTime)))) as a

      inner join 

      (SELECT * FROM [AcetateWeight].[dbo].[AW_FilterPOActuals] WHERE /*DAY=@DateTime AND Shift=@Shift and */KDF=@Equipment) as b
      ON 
    a.DateTime >= b.StartDate AND a.DateTime<= b.CompletionDate
)
```

Answer (score 0):

ceil округляет в верхнюю сторону

```
update tablename set ID=ceil(ID/20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написал так:
set ID = ID/20 +1

В MSSQL "/" - [целочисленное деление](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_integer_division.html).

Comment: Похоже что так, Round не нужен, но у автора похоже проблема в другом